# Is there a simpler way to chain promises from MongoDB results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

This function lists all collections in a MongoDB database, with the number of documents in each collection ([bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) promises).

```
function listMongoCollections(db) {
    var promises = []
    db.listCollections().toArray().then((docs) => {

        docs.forEach((doc) => {

            promises.push(
                new Promise((resolve) => {
                    db.collection(doc.name).count().then((count) => {
                        doc.count = count
                        resolve()
                    })
                })
            )
        })

        return Promise.all(promises)
    })
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Using this method will flood an app with code, and I haven't even included error handling.

Comment: You can try out Q. A tool for creating and composing asynchronous promises in JavaScript http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/

Comment: I don't see Q doing anything bluebird can't

Comment: @PålThingbø as a contributor of both Q and Bluebird - I can confirm that statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a few things:

- use `.map` to *transform* an array of collections into an array of promises, instead of `.push`ing into an array manually.
- avoid wrapping promises in new Promises.
- nest `.then` as little as possible. In the following example, notice how the first part just returns an array of promises. Only before returning the main function we wrap it in an `.all` promise.

```js
function listMongoCollections(db) {
    const docs = db.listCollections().toArray().then(docs => {
        return docs.map(doc => {
            return db.collection(doc.name).count().then(count => {
                doc.count = count
                return doc;
            });
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(docs);
}
```

You can "simplify" it further by removing the `return`s and the intermediate `docs` constant.

```js
function listMongoCollections(db) {
    return Promise.all(
        db.listCollections().toArray().then(docs => 
            docs.map(doc => 
                db.collection(doc.name).count().then(count => {
                    doc.count = count
                    return doc;
                })
            )
        )
    );
}
```

And perhaps with `async`/`await` we can make it even easier to read (although I'm not too familiar with it):

```js
async function listMongoCollections(db) {
    let docs = await db.listCollections().toArray();
    docs = docs.map(async doc => {
        doc.count = await db.collection(doc.name).count();
        return doc;
    });
    return Promise.all(docs);
}
```

These are just examples, Mongo might offer even better solutions.

Comment: Since these are Bluebird promises, you can use [`.map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/map.html) and [`.all()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/all.html) (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/f8f558b0125c950722629d0b76e4dd49)).

Comment: Just a small critique, which is HIGHLY debatable, but IMO leaving out the `return`s definitely does not improve readability. At a quick glance it's as if the functions return nothing, until you realise there are no curly brackets. Anyway, this is probably more of a critique of the fat arrow syntax than your solution, but maybe you should add a note that the functions definitely DO have to return the promises.

Comment: Totally, that's why I said and double-quoted _"simplify"_, not "improve readability".  Robert's gist in the comment is actually a better solution

Comment: This is by far the best answer I've seen for promise antipatterns, anywhere. Thank you.